# SSRS Pass Parameter via URL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following report URL:

`/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fcMIS%2fgradebookProfileView`

I'm trying to pass the parameter `TG` via the URL so it looks like so:

`/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fcMIS%2fgradebookProfileView&TG=10BEE%20C`

However this doesn't work, how can I make this work so that it automatically enters `10BEE C` into the parameter textbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `/Reports/` front end to pass parameters, you have to use the web services end point to pass the parameter (normally at `/ReportServer/`). It should still present the Report Viewer interface just like it does on the Reports url.

But your URL would become:

```
/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fcMIS%2fgradebookProfileView&rs:Command=Render&TG=10BEE+C
```

Two things of note. The URL parameter name must match the report parameter name, not the prompt. Also, spaces are encoded to `+` instead of `%20`.

Comment: Nice one on the `+` for spaces, especially for your last parameters that may need ending in spaces.