# SQL Server Reporting Services url parameters not working

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, msdn

I cannot correctly pass the parameters to a SQL Server Reporting server. The report page is displayed, but the Report Viewer Web Part’s parameter prompts are still empty and nothing is run.

The following url takes me to the correct report page, where I can manually select the parameters, then click the "View Report" button and get a report.
`http://MyServer/ReportServer?%2fProjects%2fProject_Report`

The following are in the report webpage source:

```
<label for="ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"><span>Country</span></label>
```

and

```
<option selected="selected" value="0">&lt;Select&nbsp;a&nbsp;Value&gt;</option>
<option value="1">Country01Name</option>
<option value="2">Country02Name</option>
<option value="3">Country03NameFirst&nbsp;Country03NameLast</option>
<option value="4">Country04Name</option>
<option value="5">Country05NameFirst&nbsp;Country05NameLast</option>
```

However, neither of the following work:

- using the parameter label:

  ```
  http://MyServer/ReportServer?%2fProjects%2fProject_Report&rs:Command=Render&rp:Country=Country01Name
  ```
- using the parameter name directly:

  ```
  http://MyServer/ReportServer?%2fProjects%2fProject_Report&rs:Command=Render&rp:ctl32_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue=Country01Name
  ```

What am I doing wrong?

The following sources did not help me

- [MSDN URL Access Parameter Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx)
- [MSDN Pass a Report Parameter Within a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx)
- [SO Passing parameter via url to SQL Server Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003663/ssrs-pass-parameter-via-url)
- [SO SSRS Pass Parameter via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003663/ssrs-pass-parameter-via-url)

Comment: Create a JavaScript function that returns a string to add the parameters values to the url

Comment: Thanks @Gregg.  Any idea why this is not working as it should?

Comment: BTW, I cannot change the html of the reports page.

Comment: After I add the parameter manually then inspect the element, I get the following: 

`<td class="ParamEntryCell" style="padding-right:0px;">
<div id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl09">
  <input name="ReportViewerControl$ctl04$ctl09$txtValue" type="text" value="11220" size="30" id="ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl09_txtValue" class="null">
         
</div>
</td>`  



Which ID should I add to the url?

Comment: Also, anything I put after the `&`, `:`, and `=` at the end of the following link makes absolutely no change to the report page `http://visreport/ReportServer?%2fProjects%2fOne-line_Project_Report&:=` .   However, removing any of those characters results in "Reporting Services Error   The path of the item '/Projects/One-line_Project_Report,:' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was not naming the parameters correctly, as the correct name is not listed on the Report Viewer, the webpage source or elements.

The process I completed to find the correct parameter names and generate a working url, was:

1. set the parameters on the Report Viewer manually,
2. generate the report - which adds a menu bar to the Report Viewer frame,
3. click on the "Export to Data Feed" button on the new menu bar,
4. download the *.atomsvc file,
5. open the *.atomsvc in a text editor,
6. copy the `href=` url into another file,
7. replace all `&amp;` with `&` and `%3A` with `:`in the url,
8. change `Format=ATOM` to `Format=HTML4.0` to render the report in the browser,

   - other [formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx) can be set in the url
9. (Optional) delete the parameters that I do not need set
10. (Optional) add `&rc:Parameters=Collapsed` to the end of the url to collapse the parameter menu.

This gave me a working url that generated the report automatically and displayed in browser or started to download a file in the format set by the `Format=` parameter.

Comment: I ended up figuring out I had the parameter name wrong.  But this method was awesome in helping me identify what I was missing.  Thanks.