# Passing ListBox values to a report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, listbox, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to send off selected values from a ListBox on a form to a report via parameter passing in a URL. As of right now, I don't have access to the report itself to edit right now. Reading up on SSRS parameters passing through URLs, it is stated to just declare the variable multiple times, but trying that doesn't get me anywhere.

What I want for the end result is the user to choose the values from a form, click a button and have the report open in a new browser window. Up until now I can deal with different datatypes, but the listboxes are something I have never encountered before and can't find much information about.

My current logic for this is to loop through the listbox selections, and keep the values stored until I generate the url. When the window is opened, I want only the selected values from the listbox on my form to be the only values selected in the SSRS report. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what does the URL looks like? don't need server address

Comment: `FileNameReport&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Command=Render&VAR1:=parm1&VAR2:=parm2&VAR3:=(name1,name2)` As of right now, looking more into it online, someone suggested to give `VAR3` a list as such before sending in, but I do believe it should look something like this, correct? `FileNameReport&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Command=Render&VAR1:=parm1&VAR2:=parm2&VAR3:=name1&VAR3=name2` This is assuming Var3 is the listbox values.

Comment: Repeating the parameter is the correct way. what is the part before FileNameReport it should start with "?"

Comment: Oh yeah, it's just `ReportServer?`. But that being said, thanks for informing me that it is the latter way, I'll have to figure out a different way from my current implementation.

Comment: So you are trying to create a URL from options/selection on a form and open a web browser to that URL? that isn't hard but you need to know the parameters to be passed. try with fiddler to figure out your URL then you can implement whatever report you are trying to generate

Comment: try looking over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187372/sql-server-reporting-services-url-parameters-not-working

Comment: Definitely helpful! Now the problem I'm running into here is the selections aren't appearing in the listbox that's on the form itself.

Comment: you'll need to add whatever you want to that list.

Comment: I mean, it already is. Both list boxes (on my form, and on the report) are grabbed from the same query that exists in the database. The URL shows that it is working correctly: `..?/RptName&rc:Parameters=Collapsed&rs:Command=Render&DATE1=01-Jan-2014&DATE2=30-Oct-2017&VAR3=parm1&VAR3=parm2&VAR3=parm3&VAR3=parm4&VAR3=parm5` where VAR3 is the listbox on the report. Everything else is set, but the listbox now just remains blank.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you need multi select or not

```
    ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended
    ListBox1.Items.Add("1")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("2")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("3")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("4")
```

get the selection from the list box like this

```
    For Each xSelection As String In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        MsgBox(xSelection)
    Next
```

Comment: I did turn on multi-select for this. Turns out the values I'm querying are from different databases, and I was simply selecting values that didn't exist in both databases. Once I selected ones that existed in both, the report worked just fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Phlex no problems bud